# Maven UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: java, maven, utf-8

When I run below code with two different project I get different outputs.

```
    String myString = "Türkçe Karakter Testi : ğüşiöçĞÜİŞÇÖĞ";
    String value = new String(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(value);
```

First project is non-maven java application created in Netbeans 8.2. And it gives me following result which i expect.

"Türkçe Karakter Testi : ğüşiöçĞÜİŞÇÖĞ"

And second project is  maven java application project which is created in same way with following pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

This project gives me:

"TÃ¼rkÃ§e Karakter Testi : ÄŸÃ¼ÅŸiÃ¶Ã§Ä?ÃœÄ°Å?Ã‡Ã–Ä?"

I checked both file with notepad++ and both of them are encoded with UTF-8

Comment: Similar Question: [Java encoding with Eclipse and Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471401/java-encoding-with-eclipse-and-maven)

Comment: @devpuh although this question had nothing to do with Maven actually.

Comment: Yeah, but i  get different result with same code on both project. I cant figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the encoding from your `new String()` constructor, so it's using the default encoding of your platform which **isn't** `UTF-8` (looks like some variant of `ISO-8859-1`).

If you use the following code (which doesn't make much sense, but shows the default encoding botching things), you'll see that it's printed properly everywhere.

```
String myString = "Türkçe Karakter Testi : ğüşiöçĞÜİŞÇÖĞ";
String value = new String(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(value);
```

What's the lesson here? Always specify the encoding to use when dealing with `byte/character` conversion! This includes such methods as  `String.getBytes()`, `new String()` and `new InputStreamReader()`.

This is just one of the many ways that character encoding can bite you in the behind. It may seem like a simple problem, but it catches unsuspecting developers all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I also often faced with the same problems.

---

## Configuring Maven Character Encoding

### The problem

- **Run my code in IDE (idea/eclipse)**. All correct. Output had correct encoding and in the console and in output files.
- **Run my app after built Maven**. When I try to run my App (jar) built with help maven `mvn clean install`
  I got incorrect values in output related to incorrect encoding.
  In the **console** and **in output files** which were generated in my app I saw incorrect and unexpected symbols
- **Warning in your console**. This warning means that you have not set any character encoding for your project/environment.
  Let's solve this problem. There are a couple of options you can consider.

```
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

---

## Configuring Maven Character Encoding

### 1. Properties

A most popular and common way to set **Maven Character Encoding** is to use `properties`. These properties are supported by most plugins. These properties are easy to add. Just add them as a child element of the project element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    [...]
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    [...]
</project>
```

### 2. Maven Resources Plugin

You can also specify Maven Character Encoding using the maven resources plugin.

The only drawback is that you have to include this plugin to your Maven `pom.xml` file.

**JUST ADD THIS PLUGIN** - It`s always helped me ))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    [...]
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

### 3. Commandline

If you cannot alter the source code of a maven project, or you need to specify maven character encoding on a built server like Jenkins, Hudson, or Bamboo you can also add the encoding through the command line.

```
mvn -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dproject.reporting.outputEncoding=UTF-8 clean deploy
```

### 4. Maven Options

If you do a lot of small projects for personal gain you can also set this property globally in `MAVEN_OPTS`. The only drawback is that if you share your code base with another developer then the developer also has to add these `MAVEN_OPTS`. That’s why I do not recommend it.

```
set MAVEN_OPTS= -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

---

@See [How to Configure Maven Character Encoding](https://memorynotfound.com/configure-maven-character-encoding/)